# full angularjs calendar some dates hides after change month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, calendar, fullcalendar

I have angularjs full calendar. When I populate calendar its show red line on my schedule dates, but when I go next month like MAY and back to april, some dates are hides. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
appendScheduleToCalendar(schedule_entry) {
    var event = {};
    event.start = new Date(schedule_entry.sch_start);
    event.end = new Date(schedule_entry.sch_end);
    event.title = schedule_entry.title;
    if (schedule_entry.available) {
      event.className = ['cal_available'];
    } else {
      event.className = ['cal_unavailable'];
    }
    //event.sch_type = schedule_entry.sch_type;
    event._id = schedule_entry._id;
    this.eventSources[0].push(event);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: you're not adding the event the correct way. When you click prev/next, the view is re-rendered and all events refetched from the event sources (which presumably fetch server-side data, or other static data). Use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/ with the "stick" parameter set `true` to add your event to the calendar. Also consider saving it to the server if you want it to persist the next time te calendar page is loaded.